# How to check logged data about connected devices over wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, ip

I want to know which log file I have to check to see the mac and IP addresses of connected devices over wifi, if this can't be done, I need some demon that stores that data in a logfile. And also how to do mac filtering with the wifi ap with gufw. I use Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Try `dmesg -T`command

Comment: I tried it, but I need that info and its very old, from 2 or 3 weeks ago. That's why I am asking about some kind of log. And that command only shows recent messages.